# How to split a large generic Python object into chunks

Tags: python, object, split, pickle, large-data

I have a large generic Python object which I have no information about.
I need to split this object into smaller chunks for storage needs.

Hope someone can help, Omer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#module-pickle) it and split the resulting data.

You can't serialize only "a part" of an object because there's no such thing in the general case as "a part of an object", you need knowledge of its internals to be able to split it into parts -- which you stated you don't have.

However, you can use [`pickle.dump`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#pickle.dump) (that writes to a file-like object) and pass it a custom file-like object that would split the resulting data instead as it receives it.

E.g. here's a file-like object that would write data to files in 2GiB chunks (in the example, I set the chunk size to 4MiB instead):

```
class SplitFile(object):
    def __init__(self, name_pattern, chunk_size=2*1024**3):
        self.name_pattern = name_pattern
        self.chunk_size = chunk_size
        self.file = None
        self.part = -1
        self.offset = None

    def write(self, bytes):
        if not self.file:  self._split()
        while True:
            l = len(bytes)
            wl = min(l, self.chunk_size - self.offset)
            self.file.write(bytes[:wl])
            self.offset += wl
            if wl == l: break
            self._split()
            bytes = bytes[wl:]

    def _split(self):
        if self.file:  self.file.close()
        self.part += 1
        self.file = open(self.name_pattern % self.part, "wb")
        self.offset = 0

    def close(self):
        if self.file:  self.file.close()

    def __del__(self):
        self.close()

import random
big_object = [random.random() for _ in range(1000000)]
import pickle
dest = SplitFile("data.part%02d.pickle", 4*1024**2)
pickle.dump(big_object, dest)
```

After running the example, we have:

```
$ ls -l *.pickle
-rwxrwx---+ 1 Sasha None 4194304 Dec  4 16:02 data.part00.pickle
-rwxrwx---+ 1 Sasha None 4194304 Dec  4 16:02 data.part01.pickle
-rwxrwx---+ 1 Sasha None 4194304 Dec  4 16:02 data.part02.pickle
-rwxrwx---+ 1 Sasha None 4194304 Dec  4 16:02 data.part03.pickle
-rwxrwx---+ 1 Sasha None 4194304 Dec  4 16:02 data.part04.pickle
-rwxrwx---+ 1 Sasha None  294912 Dec  4 16:02 data.part05.pickle
```

Comment: can I use pickle on a phrase of an object? so I can pickle it by chunks

Comment: @OmerB I'm not sure what you mean by "phrase". `pickle` serializes an object as a whole, but you have some control on how the resulting data flows. E.g. [`pickle.dump`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#pickle.dump) writes to a file-like object, so you can pass it some custom file-like object that would accept some data, then block until it can accept more or something.

Comment: yes this is exactly what I want to do, but I don't know how to send only a part of a generic object to the dump function. I need a way to treat objects like binary sequence or something like that.

Comment: @OmerB see the update. (I leave reading the data back as an exersize to the reader.)